# Changing notification title depending on user action? How to do that since onCreate is called before onStartCommand?

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I have a method called `makeNotificationAndStartForeground` that I call here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
    makeNotificationAndStartForeground(MyService.class, "Service", "Starting...",NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

The two string are the Title and the text content of the notification.
However I want to set the title and the text content depending on the action selected by the user.
The issue I am facing is that onCreate method is called before the onStartCommand, hence how would I set the title and the the text content if I am able to read the action only after the notification is created?

Unless of course I need to set a dummy title and content when building a notification and then change it into the onStartCommand?

Comment: Please elaborate more, this is `onCreate` of any activity? Why do you have to call `makeNotificationAndStartForeground` in `onCreate`

Comment: Because notification is supposed to be created just once, hence why in onCreate.